# Cliente SOAP FATCA Agencia Tributaria java

Tags: java, soap

Buenas estoy tratando de consumir el SOAP de la agencia tributaria de FATCA (290). No consigo recibir una respuesta valida recibiendo una excepcion SOAPFaultException. Mi codigo con el que consumo el SOAP es:

```
Receipt response = null;
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(null, null);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, null);
TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();

tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLS");
tlsParams.setKeyManagers(kmf.getKeyManagers());
DeclarationService service = new DeclarationService(Fatca.class.getResource("xsd/FatcaNtnlDeclaration_v2.0.wsdl"));
Declaration soap = service.getDeclare();

((HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(soap).getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
SOAPFault fault = null;
try {
    response = soap.declare(data);
} catch (SOAPFaultException ex) {
    ex.getStackTrace();
    LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
    fault = ex.getFault();
}
return response;
```

Cualquier ayuda seria de agradecer.

Comment: Yo por junio ya desarrolle esto en PHP y acabe por no usar SOAP para la comunicación por los fallos que daba (hay un maldito proxy en la AEAT que fastidia la mitad de las comunicaciones de SOAP por el dominio que pone). Finalmente y a día de hoy ando usando CURL.

Comment: Tienes algun problema con CURL? Sabes algún ejemplo de envío de XML con CURL con java?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar CURL para las comunicaciones en lugar de SOAP, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
 $var_header = [ 'Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8' ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Soap Client");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $var_header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);  // aqui le pones la consulta XML
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

        //SSL
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); //=3
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $ruta_pem_publica);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $ruta_pem_privada);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $contrasenia_pem);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'sessionid=' . date("Ymd"));

        //Parse cURL response
        $response     = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errorno = curl_errno($ch);

        if ($curl_errorno == CURLE_OK)   // si ha ido todo bien
        {
            $curl_statuscode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $header_size     = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $info            = curl_getinfo($ch);

            $header = substr($response, 0, $info['header_size']);
            $body   = substr($response, -$info['download_content_length']);

            //print_r($header);  // esta variable contiene la cabecera de respuesta
            //print_r($body); // esta variable contiene el cuerpo de la respuesta. ( en XML)

            $resultado = [
                'finalizada' => true,
                'error'      => null,
                'cabecera'   => $header,
                'cuerpo'     => $body
            ];

        } else  // si la conexion ha dado problemas
        {

            $curl_errormsg = curl_error($ch);
            //echo $curl_errormsg;

            $resultado = [
                'finalizada' => false,
                'error'      => $curl_errormsg,
                'cabecera'   => null,
                'cuerpo'     => null
            ];
        }

        //Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        //dd($URL, $resultado, $xml);

        return $resultado;
```

ANTIGUA RESPUESTA

```
Yo por junio ya desarrolle esto en PHP y acabe por no usar SOAP para la comunicación por los fallos que daba (hay un maldito proxy en la AEAT que fastidia la mitad de las comunicaciones de SOAP por el dominio que pone). Finalmente y a día de hoy ando usando CURL.
```

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. No tendrás un ejemplo de esto pero con java, no?

Comment: Aunque suelo programar en java, nunca se me dio el caso de tener que usar curl, pero supongo que con un simple socket con parámetros valdrá, sino hay librerías de curl también, pero no son oficiales y nunca las use.

Comment: Revisar [answer], si deseas realizar una respuesta trata de desarrollarla, de lo contrario los usuarios de la comunidad la reportarán como de baja calidad.